# Uploading files using the Settings API

Tags: php, settings-api

I've used the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) in the past to output text inputs and checkboxes but am unsure if I can use file inputs.

My [add_settings_field()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) is:

```
add_settings_field( '1', 'File 1', array( $this, 'my_callback' ), 'files', 'files' );
```

My callback function:

```
public function my_callback() {     
    echo '<input type="file" name="file" />';
}
```

I assume the next step is to handle the image upload. My problem is how do I do this using the Settings API? I am aware I can set a callback function as the 3rd parameter in [register_setting()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) so my guess is I can use [wp_handle_upload()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) in that callback. I'm looking for some guidance or confirmation that this is the approach I should take. Thanks in advance.